# Running python script from wscript fails to activate conda

Tags: python, vbscript, anaconda, conda, wsh

For some reasons I would like to execute a python script from a vbs-script. It seems that conda isn't activated when I run the script. The pythonfile ImportPandas.py has the following code:

```
print('\n-----------------------\n')
try:
    import pandas as pd
    print('Pandas was successfully imported')
except ImportError as error:
    print('Failed to import pandas\n\n%s\n' %error)
print('\n-----------------------\n')
    
input('Press key to stop')
```

I've done the following tests and have no clue how to fix the problems.

**1. Run python**
vbs-script:

```
Dim objShell 
Dim PythonExe
Dim PythonScript

Set ObjShell = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")

PythonExe = """C:\Users\XS693E\Anaconda3\envs\py38\python.exe"""
PythonScript = """C:\Users\XS693E\ImportPandas.py"""

objShell.Run PythonExe & " " & PythonScript
```

[image: Result 1]

**2. Start python without starting a script**

If I choose to only start python but not executing a script, I get a warning that conda is not activated, which I believe is the root problem.

```
Dim objShell 
Dim PythonExe

Set ObjShell = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")

PythonExe = """C:\Users\XS693E\Anaconda3\envs\py38\python.exe"""

objShell.Run PythonExe
```

[image: Result 2]

**3. Import directly in Anaconda Promptshell**

[image: Result 3]

Comment: Have you tried anything from http://conda.io/activation?

Comment: Yes, I've tried some of the commands, but I still get the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a workaround, here is the visual basic code. Triple quotation marks is only needed if the path has blank spaces in it.

```
Dim objShell 
Dim PythonExe
Dim PythonScript

Set ObjShell = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")

PythonExe = "conda activate py38  & python "
PythonScript = """C:\Users\XS693E\ImportPandas.py"""

objShell.Run "cmd /C " & PythonExe & PythonScript
```

This script is equivalent with writing the following in command line directly into the terminal.

[image: Equivalent command line]